# how can I check if a tsqlconnection is open?

Tags: c++builder, dbexpress

after an unsuccesfull login:

```
mytsqlconnection->Open();
if(mytsqlconnection->ConnectionState == csStateOpen)
{
 ...
}
```

the "if" returns true. How can I check if the connection is really open? Do I have to execute a query and catch the exception? Thanks in advance.

Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a matter of driver. I used the dbexpora.dll that came with cppbuilder6 (right-click on dbexpora.dll give no info about version). I change driver and everything works fine: Open() raise the exception, ConnectionState is set as expected. Thankyou.

Francesco

Answer (score 0):

If the login fails, `Open()` should be raising an exception.  The `ConnectionState` property is not set to `csStateOpen` unless Open() is successful in establishing a connection to the DB without error.

Comment: I'm developing with c++builder6, dbexpora.dll driver, oracle11g. Here is the code:            DBXConnection->Params->Values["USER_NAME"] = "fakeusername";
DBXConnection->Params->Values["PASSWORD"] = "fakepassword";
DBXConnection->ConnectionState;
DBXConnection->LoginPrompt = false;
try
{
 DBXConnection->Open();
}
catch (Exception* E)
{
   ShowMessage(E->Message);
        DBXConnection->Connected = false;
        return;
} Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I cannot comment on Oracle, as I use DBX to connect to SQLServer instead, but Open() does raise an exception for me if it fails.  On a side note, you should catch exceptions as const references, not as pointers: `catch (const Exception& E)`.